# ReSharper directive to ignore false positive HTML errors from Underscore template

Tags: html, resharper, underscore.js-templating

We run ReSharper command line tool (v. 1.0.60) as a part of build scenario in VSTS. Recently we started using Underscore HTML templates and our builds started to fail because of ReSharper warnings - turns out it cannot tolerate Underscore templates.

A part of it looks like this which I should admit may appear as invalid HTML:

```
<select class="form-control input-medium" data-member data-key="Id" name="Stage" id="Stage">
    <% _.each(stageReference, function(field) { %>
        <option value="<%=field.Id%>" <%= (data && data.Stage && data.Stage.Code == field.Code) ? "selected" : "" %>><%=field.DisplayName%></option>
    <% }) %>
</select>
```

ReSharper log:

```
2017-03-30T16:10:45.3365132Z ##[error]...\template.html(6,1): error : R# '>' or '/>' expected
2017-03-30T16:10:45.3365132Z ##[error]...\template.html(6,1): error : R# Unexpected token
2017-03-30T16:10:45.3365132Z ##[error]...\template.html(6,1): error : R# Unexpected token
```

How do I disable this check or at least make it false positive? Are there any code directives like those:

```
// ReSharper disable Mvc.ControllerNotResolved
// ReSharper disable Mvc.ActionNotResolved
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a straight solution, but worked around this by adding an ignore files by mask directive to ReSharper code inspection configuration:

[image]

As the result my `<solution_name>.sln.DotSettings` file looks like this now:

```
<wpf:ResourceDictionary xml:space="preserve" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:ss="urn:shemas-jetbrains-com:settings-storage-xaml" xmlns:wpf="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <s:Boolean x:Key="/Default/CodeInspection/ExcludedFiles/FileMasksToSkip/=_002A_002Dtemplate_002Ehtml/@EntryIndexedValue">True</s:Boolean>
</wpf:ResourceDictionary>
```

This file should be included with the solution and pushed to the remote source. Then when the build agent runs ReSharper command line tool, it automatically reads the local solution rules and uses them when inspecting the code.

Also check if ReSharper command tool runs with `--disable-settings-layers:SolutionShared` or `--no-buildin-settings` keys and remove them, otherwise your `.sln.DotSettings` configuration file will be ignored.